# Capitalize first letter of each word using reduce in Javascript

Tags: javascript

The function should capitalize the first letter of each word in the string then **return** the capitalized string.

--- Examples

```
capitalize('a short sentence') --> 'A Short Sentence'

capitalize('a lazy fox') --> 'A Lazy Fox'
```

I got it working without using `reduce` but I want to be better at reduce but I can't get it to work.

```
capitalize = str => {
  //V1
  return str
  .split(" ")
  .map(w => {
    return w.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + w.slice(1);
  })
  .join(" ");
};
```

**Me trying with reduce:**

```
capitalize = str => {
    let index = 0;
      const arr = str.split("");
      return arr.reduce((acc, curr, i) => {
        console.log(acc);
        if (acc === " ") {
          return curr.toUpperCase();
        }
        index = i;
      }, arr[index]);
    };
```

Comment: what if the input is something like  `heLLo` ? what is desired output in this case ?

Comment: @CodeManiac thanks for you question. I took a look to the test cases and none of them have an example like that so I guess it doesn't matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to treat the string as a character array, and to uppercase the character if it's either the first element in the array, or if the preceding element is a space:

```js
const capitalize = str => [...str].reduce(
  (s, c, i, a) => s + (i === 0 || a[i - 1] === ' ' ? c.toUpperCase() : c),
  ''
);

console.log(capitalize('a short sentence'));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to use `reduce` here, it would probably be easiest to (similar to what you're doing originally) iterate over *words* rather than letters, where the accumulator is the capitalized string you're in the progress of creating. The only tricky part is checking whether you need to add a space before inserting the changed word or not:

```js
const capitalize = str => {
  const arr = str.split(" ");
  return arr.reduce((acc, word) => (
    acc + (acc === '' ? '' : ' ') // add space before next word if necessary
    + word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1))
  , '');
};
    
    
console.log(capitalize('a short sentence')) // --> 'A Short Sentence'
console.log(capitalize('a lazy fox')) // --> 'A Lazy Fox'
```

Still, that's not so readable. I think `.map` / `.join` looks better.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function capitalize(string) {
  return string.split(' ').reduce((accumulatedString, currentWord) =>  
  accumulatedString.concat(currentWord[0].toUpperCase() + currentWord.slice(1)), []).join(' ')
}

console.log(capitalize('a lazy fox'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just using CSS:

```css
p {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<p>a short sentence</p>
```

Using JavaScript [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const str = 'a lazy fox';
const capitalize = str => str
  .split(' ')
  .reduce((a, c) => {
    const word = `${c.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}${c.slice(1)}`;
    return a ? `${a} ${word}` : word;
  }, '');

console.log(capitalize(str));
```

Comment: lol thanks tho. I know I can do that but I want to be better at JS and specially ```reduce()```

Comment: your code adds a space at the beginning of every sentence

Answer (score 1):

Check this one:

```js
const a = 'a lazy fox';
const b = 'a short sentence';
const capitalizeAllWord  = str => str && str.split(" ")
      .reduce((acc, curr)=> [...acc, `${curr.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}${curr.slice(1)}`] ,[])
      .join(" ");

console.log(capitalizeAllWord(a));
console.log(capitalizeAllWord(b));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code .It will helps you.

```js
     const input = 'a short sentenc'
     output = input.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + input.substring(1);
     console.log(output)
```